Anylogic TrainMoveTo - How to access the route evaluation outside the trainMoveTo block?
In Anylogic a route is only evaluated and created when a train enters the trainMoveTo block. I would like to access the route evaluation/creation before the train enters this block. Is this possible?
I haven't tried anything as of yet but the Anylogic help guides say that the route is only available within the block.

pls only use the "anylogic" tag, avoids confusing other SOF users :) See https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

No. The route is only calculated upon entering the block. Also, you have little to no "say" in the route calculation, except for what the layout and blocks allow you to do :)

In this case, if you need an specific route, you can create your own internal loop and mapping and use the MoveTo block to move step-by-step on the route (to check if conditions changed, etc). It is not trivial but it should not be too hard to manually control everything routing-related; it was needed on one project where we adjusted speed for ramp conditions and had road blockages and the default route finder for AnyLogic was not made to account for that

very cool idea :)

Hi, thank you for the response and the suggestions. Much appreciated.

Hi Benjamin, I have found routing functions in the RailSettings block. Could this work?

Don't know, try it :)
